# How to hide notification when new one comes up with toastr

Tags: javascript, toastr

I have notifications popping up in my application, I want when new notification comes, the old one to hide (I don't want two notifications to show at the same time).

How to get that effect with toastr?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use the `clear` function :

```
toastr.clear();
```

Hope this will helps you.

Source : **[officiel documentation](https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr)**.

Comment: Can you tell me how can I clear only info notifications, is that possible?

Comment: I think that is not possible since it's not covered in the documentation.

Comment: @V.Dimitrov you can get `toastr.getContainer().children()`, loop through it to filter info notifications and then call `toastr.clear($toastElement)` for each.